# Writing a while for several ip running shell script

Tags: mysql, shell, ip, sh, snmp

my script is working partly, or it wass until i wanted to be able to run a while loop, as long as there is IP in the IP variable, i have searched for a while loop in shell on google, but i cant quite figure out how to write it, so i can just add several ip's and run it.

I'm from denmark, so the variables can look quite odd ^^

```
#!/bin/bash
# snmp printer status
#Function takes two arguments: ip oid
#function snmpget()
#{
#    snmpdata=`snmpget -v2c -c public $1 $2 | cut -d" " -f3-`
#    echo $snmpdata
#}
        kunde='fkt'
        ip[0]= '172.29.8.250'
        ip[1]= '172.29.8.200'
let a=0
while [[ $a -lt ${#ip[*]} ]] ; do
let a+=1
serienummer=$(snmpget -v2c -c public $ip iso.3.6.1.2.1.43.5.1.1.17.1 | cut -d" " -f4-)
model=$(snmpget -v2c -c public $ip iso.3.6.1.2.1.43.5.1.1.16.1 | cut -d" " -f4-)
ialt=$(snmpget -v2c -c public $ip iso.3.6.1.4.1.1347.43.10.1.1.12.1.1 | cut -d" " -f4-)
a3f=$(snmpget -v2c -c public $ip iso.3.6.1.4.1.1347.42.2.1.1.1.8.1.1 | cut -d" " -f4-)
a3sh=$(snmpget -v2c -c public $ip iso.3.6.1.4.1.1347.42.2.1.1.1.7.1.1 | cut -d" " -f4-)
a4sh=$(snmpget -v2c -c public $ip iso.3.6.1.4.1.1347.42.2.1.1.1.7.1.3 | cut -d" " -f4-)
a4f=$(snmpget -v2c -c public $ip iso.3.6.1.4.1.1347.42.2.1.1.1.8.1.3 | cut -d" " -f4-)
hostnavn=$(snmpget -v2c -c public $ip iso.3.6.1.4.1.1347.40.10.1.1.5.1 | cut -d" " -f4-)
scan=$(snmpget -v2c -c public $ip iso.3.6.1.4.1.1347.46.10.1.1.5.3 | cut -d" " -f4-)
mysql --host=localhost --user=username --password=password status_printer -e "INSERT INTO status (serienummer,model,ialt,a3f,a3sh,a4sh,a4f,hostnavn,scan)
 VALUES('${serienummer}','${model}','${ialt}','${a3f}','${a3sh}','${a4sh}','${a4f}','${hostnavn}','${scan}');"
done
```

Comment: I'd think that `for ip in ${ips[@]} ; do` does exactly what you need, with less complication?  Do you agree?  Note that I call the array `ips` and the individual address `ip`, but that's just an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Glenn explained very well why your script fails, here's the way I'd write it, because a for loop is a more natural fit in this context.  I also show how you can get rid of having to manage the index manually

```
# "classic" initialization
ips[0]= '172.29.8.250'
ips[1]= '172.29.8.200'
# or alternatively - no need to manage the index
ips=('172.29.8.250' '172.29.8.200')
# or even
ips=()
ips+=('172.29.8.250')
ips+=('172.29.8.200')

for ip in ${ips[@]} ; do
  serienummer=$(snmpget -v2c -c public $ip iso.3.6.1.2.1.43.5.1.1.17.1 | cut -d" " -f4-)
  # and so on
done
```

Answer (score 1):

You have

```
ip[0]= '172.29.8.250'
ip[1]= '172.29.8.200'
let a=0
while [[ $a -lt ${#ip[*]} ]] ; do
    let a+=1
    serienummer=$(snmpget -v2c -c public $ip iso.3.6.1.2.1.43.5.1.1.17.1         | cut -d" " -f4-)
    # ....................................^^
```

You're looping the index variable, but you don't use it. You could change that `$ip` to `${ip[a]}`, or use fvu's suggestion do drop the `while` loop and use `for` (which is exactly what I'd do)

Note that if you use an array variable without specifying an index, it seems to give you the first element:

```
$ ip=(one two three)
$ echo ${ip[1]}
two
$ echo $ip
one
```

and

```
$ echo ${#ip[*]}
3
$ let a=0
$ while [[ $a -lt ${#ip[*]} ]]; do
> echo $ip
> let a+=1
> done
one
one
one
```

Comment: AWESOME!! it worked :D

Now i have the issue, when a printer does not answer, the script ofcourse gives me a timeout, but how can i ignore the "missing" printer answer, and proceed to the next IP in line?

Kim